# Changing datetime format on mschart axis

Tags: c#, datetime, format, mschart, linechart

I'm using mschart to display some values over a timeperiod.

It looks something like this:

[image: a busy cat]

As you can see the first value is from 15:11 and the last from 16:10
But on the x-axis it's on displaying the days.
How can I change this?

EDIT: Changing XValueType to ChartValueType.Time leads to this:

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Does setting the X axis value type to `ChartValueType.Time` make any difference ?

Comment: Where is the property for this in mschart?

Comment: check for the series `Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time`

Comment: Good idea, but this leads to another problem...

Now it's only using hour and minute...

Comment: try setting the `ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` to `HH:mm:ss` or other as you need

Comment: Yes that's working! Thanks alot....   Make an answer and you get the points :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To show DateTime related values on the XAxis you can choose to set the `XValueType` property.

In your case `Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time` would be the right thing to display time related values.

To format the values you can use `ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` which would translate your values into the required format say like `HH:mm:ss`.

```
ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format ="HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: How to display AM/PM values ?

Comment: A little tip! Use Keywords such as #VALY{HH:mm:ss} if seconds are not displaying.

Comment: I found that I had to put chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format ="HH:mm:ss"; in my designer file before this would work.